# Can Dropzone.js be used to upload music and video files?

Tags: javascript, laravel-5, laravel-blade, dropzone.js

I have had a successful experience with Dropzone when working images and files like .doc, pdf, etc. Now I am working on a music and video website and would like to use Dropzone for the upload because of its nice experience.

Is it possible to use it for a similar purpose? Is there any documentation on it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the docs at http://www.dropzonejs.com/#configuration-options I see that it refers to files and not images only.

> There is also an `acceptedFiles` method:
>   http://www.dropzonejs.com/#config-acceptedFiles
>   You can set there the accepted type of files then (like .mp3 etc).

You can find more about Dropzone.js at https://github.com/enyo/dropzone where as I can see on issues there are several open or closed issues related with the kind of files you want to use.